# Why does my not statistically significant regression get significant when adding my crucial x-variable?

Tags: ordered-logit

Short background. My regression consist of both micro-level data (individual data collected by survey, up to 60 000 observations) and macro-level data (national macroeconomic statistics such as inflation, GDP, unemployment). The way I have combined the data is to for example match the country of the individual and the year the survey was carried out with the corresponding macro-level data for each individual. Since my micro-level data consists of 22 countries and apprx 1000 observation each, I get the same macroeconomic data for 1000 observation each.

My problem: When I do a regression (which is an ordered logistic regression since my dependent variable is ordinal) with my micro and macro data but exclude my crucial X-variable (which itself is a aggregated macroeconomic variable), I get high p-values for all of my macro-level control variables. But when I add my crucial X-variable, I get statistical significance on all of them. Why is this so? Is this a problem that I should address and how?

I have done a correlation test between all my macroeconomic data and yes, they do correlate a lot! The highest correlation is even 0.77!

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean with the error variance. Do you mean one of these?
Prob > chi2     =     0.0000
Pseudo R2       =     0.0376
Because if that's the case, when I add my crucial x-variable, the pseudo R2 increases just a little.

When you mention multicollinearity, my crucial x-variable is very correlated with all the other macroeconomic variables. Is this the issue? Do I need to remove them or can I still keep them in my model even if they are not significant?

Comment: I am doing an ordered logistic regression, so ologit in stata. My dependent variable is ordinal so that's why I'm doing it this way.

I think my main issue is that all the macroeconomic variables are heavily correlated so my model have multicollinearity. But I don't know what to do..

Comment: yeah, ignore my earlier comment; the corresponding comment for what you're doing is that adding variables can make your model fit better, reducing standard errors of coefficient estimates -- so the test-statistic for a coefficient will often tend to increase in size when adding important variables (but it's not guaranteed, because adding variables can affect the size of parameter estimates as well, and can also make multicollinearity worse)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a use-case for Hierarchical linear model/multilevel model/random-coefficient model under the family of mixed models.

HLM are useful when there are multiple levels like the macrolevel and microlevel data in your case. To understand, why your regular regression is behaving like what you have described, do read the example here: http://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol08-1/p052/p052.pdf .
It happens when you do not consider the within group effects or random effects that may be occuring in your case. Try using lmer or lme package in case you wish to use R.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Are you sure I can use that model? Since my dependent variable is an ordinal value, I thought that I needed to do an ordered logistic regression?

Comment: Since HLM is just a concept, similar logic may exist for the ordinal outcome paradigm. For instance, I came across this paper: http://www.timolsen.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/ordinal_logistic_hlm_tim_olsen1.pdf . The motivation behind telling you about the HLM tutorial is to suggest, what could have gone wrong.